# Clarification about the phrase "within [x] years of the date..."

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

Does the phrase "within [x] years of the date..." mean **before** or **after** (or both?) the specified date?
For example, in the phrase, "GRE scores taken within 5 years of the date application was received," does the applicant have to take the GRE test after the application is received, or does he/she take the test before the application date?

*Context info: Later on, in the same text, it says "TOEFL, IELTS or PTE scores taken **within the last 2 years** of the date application was received," making it clear that the applicants have to take the test before applying to the school.

Comment: I don’t think the text you refer to in your text is using clear English. I would say

Comment: Whoops. Didn’t finish my comment. I would say - **within two years previous to the date...** for meaning scores taken before, or **within two years following the date...** for meaning scores taken after. When just using “of”, it always means after: “GRE scores taken within five years of the date...” would always mean the scores were taken after

Comment: @MotherBrain I believe so too! It's not using clear English. What's bad about it, is that it is a University's website, so prospective students become confused.... (PS: it's a US University)

Comment: @MotherBrain I also sent a question to the University itself and they replied that: "Your GRE scores must be no older than 5 years from the date you submit your application to our university. " Which, if I understand well, means that you have to submit your GRE scores **within 5 years prior** to the date of application. Oh, the irony!

Comment: Yes that sentence is all over the place. It hurts my head to think about it!

Comment: Often the logic of the situation disambiguates. If the GRE is a prerequisite to having the application granted, it makes no sense that you could take it several years later.

Comment: @Barmar The whole point of the discussion was that it was unclear whether the GRE scores were prerequisite to sending the application. What the student who sent me this understood was that she could take the GRE test AFTER her application and acceptance to the University. Sometimes, Universities grant acceptance requiring the student to take certain tests after the studies have begun (e.g. language proficiency tests). So, this situation would still be logical.
  I think the comments on this page make it clear to me that the original sentence lacks clarity.

Comment: @Felicity I understand that, although 5 years seems hard to believe. If it were something like "within 6 months" it would be truly ambiguous.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this makes sense. It's for a PhD course though, they can take quite a long time...

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior